# Look for a GC friendly way to replace substring frequently

Tags: android, string, kotlin, garbage-collection, stringbuilder

My goal is simply replace the substring, but very frequently. The program runs in Android.

Such as I have a string = `{a} is a good {b}.` with a map=`{{a}=Bob, {b}=boy}`, and the result should be `Bob is a good boy.` I need to deal with such replacement for different string up to 400 times peer second because the value of map will update real time.

However I use trie tree and Aho-Corasick automaton for high perfromance, here's the core fragment:

```
    val builder: StringBuilder

    private fun replace(str: String): String {
        if (!getFail) {
            getFail()
        }
        var p = 1
        builder.setLength(0)
        for (c in str) {
            builder.append(c)
            if (c.toInt() !in 0..126) {
                continue // ignore non-ascii char
            }
            var k = trie[p][c.toInt()]
            while (k > 1) {
                // find a tag
                if (end[k] != 0) {
                    val last = builder.length - end[k]
                    // replace the tag
                    values[builder.sub(last, end[k])]?.let {
                        builder.replace1(last, end[k], it)
                    }
                    p = 0
                    break
                }
                k = fail[k] // not find
            }
            p = trie[p][c.toInt()]
        }
        return builder.toString()
    }
```

As you can see I have used `StringBuilder` to reused memory, but finally I have to call `StringBuilder.toString()` to return the result and this operation create a new string object. Meanwhile the result's lifecycle is very short and the replacement function is called very frequently. As a result JVM will GC frequently.

Any way to reuse the memory occupied by the short life result string? Or just some other solution.

Comment: Have you proof and measurements of problems, or is this pure guessing about a problem you may have?

Comment: @Kayaman In fact it is an Android App, when running this work, ram used increase 0.1M / 2s and be recycled every 25 seconds. It is strange that no GC log output. Now I am confused if it effect the performance

Comment: If you're not even getting any GC logs, it sounds like you don't have a problem.

Comment: How about implementing your your own `CharSequence` (not `String`) that first compiles your pattern for performance (knows the start and end index of each pattern and the key) and then, when you pass in a `Map` will just iterate the `CharSequence` and replace on the fly. This way - no garbage! (apart from the `Map`)

Comment: @Boris the Spider Yes, This is also mentioned in the answer  I will try later. Thank you for further explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any way to reuse the memory occupied by the short life result string?

No.

> Or just some other solution.

If you *could* change the code that uses the `String` objects generated by this method to accept a `CharSequence` instead.  Then you could pass it the `StringBuilder` instance in `builder`, and avoid the `toString()` call.

The problem is that you wouldn't be able to prevent something from casting `CharSequence` to `StringBuilder` and mutating it.  (But if the code is not security critical, you could ignore that.  It would be hard to do that by accident, especially if you use the `CharSequence` interface type when passing the `StringBuilder` around.)

The other problem is that the caller will actually be getting the same object each the time with different state.  It wouldn't be able to keep the state ... unless it called `toString()` on it.

---

But you may be worrying unnecessarily about performance.   The GC is relatively good at dealing with short-lived objects.  Assuming that an object is unreachable on the first GC cycle after it is created, it won't ever be marked or copied, and the cost of deleting it will be zero.  To a first approximation, it is the reachable objects in the "from" space that will cost you.

I would first do some profiling and GC monitoring.  Only go down the path of changing your code as above if there is clear evidence that the short lived strings *are* causing a performance problem.

(My intuition is that 400 short term strings per second should not be a problem, assuming that 1) they are not huge and 2) you picked a GC that is suitable for your use-case.)

Comment: Yes I will reappraise the effect. And `CharSequence` never come to my mind. Thanks for answer I will try tomorrow.

Comment: Since this question is about “a GC friendly way”, it must be emphasized that keeping a reference to the `StringBuilder` and reusing it, is the opposite of being “GC friendly”. Returning a `CharSequence` has a point here. The best solution is to create a new `StringBuilder` on each invocation, but to return the `StringBuilder` (as `CharSequence`), to avoid the intrinsic copy operation which happens when constructing a new `String` from the builder. You can even protect it via `CharBuffer.wrap(CharSequence)` to get a truly read-only `CharSequence` without copying overhead.

Comment: @Holger Maybe my statement is not accurate. "GC friendly" mean keep the reference to avoid GC so that no need to creat a lot of objects and free them in a short time (which cause memory churn). NOT mean release unused object as quickly as possible.

Comment: @Chenhe then you have an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). “Reduce overhead” is an actual goal. “Minimize pause time” or “maximize throughput” are actual goals. “Avoid GC” as an end in itself, is not a meaningful goal. And “memory churn” is not even a meaningful technical term at all.

Comment: @Holger But the fact is if create `StringBuilder` every time the performance would be more ugly. I just see Android document about [memory churn](https://developer.android.google.cn/topic/performance/memory.html?hl=en#churn). However in this case, creation of String object seems wont't influence the performance.

Comment: @Chenhe - If you are asking about Android GC behavior, you have tagged your question incorrectly.  The advice given in that document is tailored to the Android platform; i.e. a simpler GC and less available memory.  If you are using Oracle / OpenJDK you should consult the Oracle documentation.

Comment: And the "in fact" is not necessarily true.  A short-lived `StringBuilder` has the same properties as a short-lived `String`.  With (AFAIK) all modern Oracle / OpenJDK, "memory churn" only matters if it is excessive (e.g. millions of objects a second) or if you have to meet stringent low latency requirements.  What you are doing is premature optimization ... and it is probably a waste of your time.

Comment: @Chenhe mmh, that article uses that term without actually defining it. It says “*In practice, memory churn describes the number of allocated temporary objects that occur in a given amount of time.*” If that’s what it is all about, the term was misleading and obsolete. But the “in practice” suggests that it is actually something different, which brings us back to square one, the article doesn’t say what it is (supposed to be).

Comment: The fact that rapid allocations shorten the GC interval, is trivial, but doesn’t depend on the number of object but the *amount of memory*, which scales with the size of the string, every time you perform a (possibly hidden) copy operation. That’s why I put the focus on the copying operation in my previous comments. They costs once when they are performed (scaling with string size) and they shorten the time between GC runs more than trivial wrapper objects (again, scaling with string size). In contrast, as Stephen C said, it doesn’t matter whether you construct a `StringBuilder` or `String`.

Comment: Sorry I'm late. You are right, I inadvertently got into a XY problem about the **object 
 numbers** and **amount of memory**. I have gave up this insignificant "optimizing".